# Csharp linq selection with join in nested classes

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a C#class called school that has a list of classes (in school) which has a list of teachers which has a list of students as below. What I need to get is the comma separated list of all student names for every included teacher. How can I achieve this with linq? 
Here is the complete code:

```
class LinqTests
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");

        School rw = new School();
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            ClassInSchool sr = new ClassInSchool();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                sr.teachers.Add(new Teacher((i % 2), "" + i));
            }
            rw.classes.Add(sr);
        }
        var elems = rw.classes.Select(sr => sr.teachers)
            .Where(l2s => l2s != null)
            .Where(l2s => l2s.Any(l2 => l2.include == true));

        Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(elems, Formatting.None));

        Debug.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
    }


    class School
    {
        public List<ClassInSchool> classes;
        public School()
        {
            classes = new List<ClassInSchool>();
        }
    }

    class ClassInSchool
    {
        public List<Teacher> teachers;

        public ClassInSchool()
        {
            teachers = new List<Teacher>();
        }
    }

    class Teacher
    {
        public bool include;
        public List<string> students;
        public Teacher(int includeIn, string student)
        {
            include = Convert.ToBoolean(includeIn);
            students = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                students.Add(student + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want students I think you want the following

```
var students = rw.classes
    .SelectMany(c => c.teachers)
    .Where(t => t.include)
    .SelectMany(t => t.students);
```

Then to get a comma separated string

```
var csv = string.Join(", ", students);
```

I've removed the `null` check on the `teachers` list since you are initializing it in the `ClassInSchool` constructor.  But if you need to guard against possible `null` collections you can do this instead.

```
var students = rw.classes
    .Where(c => c.teachers != null)
    .SelectMany(c => c.teachers)
    .Where(t => t.include && t.students != null)
    .SelectMany(t => t.students);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var teachers = rw.classes.Where(x => x.teachers != null)
                     .SelectMany(x => x.teachers.Where(teacher => teacher.students != null && teacher.include));
    var allStudentsNames = teachers.SelectMany(x => x.students);
    var uniqueStudentsNames = allStudentsNames.Distinct();
    var uniqueStudentsNamesCommSeparatedList = string.Join(", ", uniqueStudentsNames);
```

You can of course chain those methods.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown... it helps me understand the return values much better..